# Estimation with complex exponent

Tags: complex-numbers

*Context* (not necessary to understand the task). I'm working through so called Eigenvalue Estimation Problem from the field of Quantum Computing. More precisely, I try to measure the inaccuracy of the quantum circuit when an eigenvalue measured is irrational (the circuit is designed for rational phases).

*The task* can be reduced to the estimation with the lower bound of an (modulus of) expression:

$$
\frac 1 {2^m} \frac {1 - e^{2\pi i \delta 2^m}} {1 - e^{2\pi i \delta }}
$$

Here $m$ is a natural number, $\delta$ is a real from $[0,1)$, $i$ is the imaginary unit.

It is known that the desired lower bound is $2 / \pi$. It is suggested to get upper bound for denominator (which is clearly $2\pi\delta$) and lower bound for numerator (which is problematic for me) and then divide them. It is known that numerator $N$ can be estimated like this: $ N > 2\pi\delta2^m(2/\pi) > 4\delta 2^m$. Can anyone explain, how to obtain the bound in the left part of the inequality?

Comment: I think that desired estimation is wrong. See code: http://cpp.sh/8qiog

Comment: Key role plays 2^(-m) factor, result lower bound cannot be without it

Comment: I suppose, that your estimation will be right only in the case, where we have fixed number m (it plays role as constant), and b converges to +0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution turns to be direct consequence of [Jordan's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan's_inequality):

$$
    \sin x \geqslant x \frac 2 {\pi}
$$

We would like to obtain lower bound for $|1 - e^{2\pi i \delta 2^m}|$, that is $|AC|$ on the following graphics with unit circle:

[image]

$OB$ is altitude and, at the same time, bisector and median, so

$$|AC| = 2 |AB| = 2 \sin {\frac a 2} \geqslant 2 \frac a 2 \frac 2 {\pi} = \frac {2a} \pi .$$

Given that $a = 2\pi \delta 2^m$ we have desired $|AC| = |1 - e^{2\pi i \delta 2^m}| \geqslant 4 \delta 2^m$. The whole fraction from the post turns to be estimated as follows:

$$
\frac 1 {2^m} \frac {1 - e^{2\pi i \delta 2^m}} {1 - e^{2\pi i \delta }}
\geqslant 
\frac 1 {2^m} \frac {4 \delta 2^m} {2 \pi \delta} = \frac 2 {\pi}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is another approach which finds more exact lower bound (you can see it in my program for example)[image]

It gives lower bound 1 (as limit)

Note, it will works only if b converges to +0 (for very small b and fixed m)